# "Browse file" window freeze code execution in pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am working on automating program that requires choosing file path.
After I click the browse button using code:

```
 dlg.child_window(auto_id='btnBrwsBinFile').click()
```

browse window opens and freeze execution of code and I cannot control the popup window.

I have tried also different approach. I have edited text filed using code:

```
   dlg['Edit'].set_text(path)
```

but then program do not see the path, it treats the field like it was never edited, like it was empty

I would like to ask if someone solved this issue before.

Comment: Can you give the name of the program you want to automate?

Comment: Hi, this software is not available for download. It is used internally in my organization.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
dlg.child_window(title='btnBrwsBinFile').click_input()
```

pywinauto documentation：https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html

You can use `UISpy.exe` to get the title, class name

Comment: Thank you for idea but this is not solution in this case. It is not a problem to get title. The  issue is that when you click the button and popup appears not even single line of code is be executed.  I have tried even using threads. Still no progress.

Comment: @starylass Do you mean once it clicks on browse button the process hangs and nothing happens? or does it exits abruptly? What exception you received? Does this action opens new window? if yes did you manage to get other elements of this window?

Comment: After executing "dlg.child_window(auto_id='btnBrwsBinFile').click()" program opens browse window and waits for user to choose file. Process is still running no exception appears.  At this point not even single line of python script is executed until browse window is open. That is how I loose control over program.